# jQuery image slider stops working after page sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm having a trouble with a jQuery image slider that works only the first time i open its page !
I have one main page, that includes via Ajax three page portions (Home, Presentation and Contact), the home portion contains the image slider !
To move through the pages, i use another jQuery page slider which includes the right portion and plays a sliding animation to show it !

So when i go for example from the home page to the presentation page, and then comeback to home ... the image slider isn't working anymore, and sometimes doesn't even appear !

What does it mean ?
How can i make sure the script is reloaded after the page slider finishes the transition, cause i think the problem comes from it ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: false,
      auto: true,
      interval: 3000,
      swap: true
    }
  });

  $(".menuButton").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    var cont = $("#container");
    var cont1 = $("#container1");

    cont1.load("parts/"+page+".html", function() {
      cont.hide("slide", {direction:"right"}, function() {
        cont1.show("slide", {direction:"left"});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is included in the portions loaded by ajax, it won't run (ajax loaded scripts are not ran by default). So basically, after the success event, just call the functions from the script.